# Is it acceptable to mix http versions on a Drupal site?

Tags: performance, http, drupal

I've recently had to make a change to a core module that means that my error pages are sent using HTTP 1.0 and the rest of my site is HTTP 1.1. Background is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162995/mysterious-number-appears-above-drupal-generated-html-when-visiting-page-for-firs) and [here](http://drupal.org/node/355170). I've seen advice that indicates that making one site speak different versions of HTTP for different pages is a Bad Idea, eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769371/404-header-http-1-0-or-1-1), but they don't say what can go wrong. It seems like http 1.1 offers some performance improvements in the form of [allowing persistent connections and better caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246859/http-1-0-vs-1-1), which are things I wouldn't want to lose if I can avoid it for some of my pages... hence the mixing of http versions.

Am I headed towards disaster? Or alternatively, is the performance improvement of http 1.1 actually small enough that I should consider ditching it for the sake of better practice?

Answer (score 0):

> I've recently had to make a change to a core module

Don't do that! If it's in any way possible, roll a module. If there is a problem with the core, please submit a patch (it will help other developers, and also make it easier for you to keep current).

The HTTP issue is a tricky one. As you have said, HTTP 1.1 adds persistent connections and things like that, which your browser may decide to use on your website. How a browser behaves if a website suddenly sends out an HTTP 1.0 I do not know, nor what happens if an HTTP 1.0 response is sent over a persistent connection.

However, the background questions you linked are for a very specific situation - where a reverse proxy (nginx) is in front of your site. If this is the case, read on:

The only agent accessing your site directly is nginx. As long as nginx works, you don't have a problem. There is no benefit to serving your website to nginx as HTTP 1.1 because it only supports 1.0 for proxying. However, nginx will transparently handle connections to your users as HTTP 1.1 - i.e. they can use persistent connections etc, while nginx is setting up and tearing down connections to the backend in the background.

My advice would therefore be, knock your entire website down to HTTP 1.0, and verify that nginx is still serving it as HTTP 1.1. You might find that the 404 header is still escaping, but I *think* nginx will properly capture and handle that, too. Test and find out!